# What will be the final temperature of water when heating at a a rate 10J/s?

Tags: thermodynamics, water

If I supply heat of rate 10W to water of mass 250g and initial temperature of water is 29 degC then what will be the final temperature of water when steady state is reached. **Water is heating in open pan.

Comment: List the equations you think would be relevant...

Comment: is this even possible without knowing what the heat loss to the environment is?

Comment: assuming heat supply is equal to heat loss and loss is completely through convection because pan is insulated from sides.

Comment: Assuming a spherical pan in a vacuum....